# TextAlign pointlabel Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have been experimenting with a multiline pointlabel (very long label) for a radar chart.
 When creating a multiline pointlabel the text in the label aligns left/right/center depending on the side of the radar chart.
 I searched and found out that the datalabel plugin https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/formatting.html#multiline-labels supports `textAlign` but there are no examples how to apply this.
 Is there a way to align the text in all the labels to center?

```js
var data = {
  labels: [
    ["very", "long label"],
    ["very", "long label"],
    ["very", "long label"]
  ],
  datasets: [{
    label: [`dataset`],
    backgroundColor: "rgba(38,120,255,0.2)",
    borderColor: "rgba(38,120,255, 1)",
    data: [90, 90, 90]
  }]
};

var options = {
  responsive: true,
  tooltips: false,
  title: {
    text: 'Basic example',
    display: true,
    position: `bottom`,
  },
  scale: {
    angleLines: {
      display: true
    },
    ticks: {
      suggestedMin: 0,
      suggestedMax: 100,
      stepSize: 25, 
      maxTicksLimit: 11,
      display: false, 
    }
  }
};

var myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
  type: 'radar',
  data: data,
  options: options
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.1.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js" integrity="sha512-Tfw6etYMUhL4RTki37niav99C6OHwMDB2iBT5S5piyHO+ltK2YX8Hjy9TXxhE1Gm/TmAV0uaykSpnHKFIAif/A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <canvas id="chart" width="500" height="450"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no option to define the text-alignment for the point labels, `textAlign` it computed depending on the angle by the function `getTextAlignForAngle` inside [`radialLinear.js`](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/src/scales/scale.radialLinear.js).

You can however overwrite `textAlign` after the chart generation using the [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api). The API offers different hooks that may be used to execute custom code. The `afterLayout` hook for example may be used as follows.

```
afterLayout: chart => {
  chart.getDatasetMeta(0).rScale._pointLabelItems.forEach(o => o.textAlign = 'center');      
}
```

Please take a look at your amended code below and see how it works.

```js
var data = {
  labels: [
    ["very", "long label"],
    ["very", "long label"],
    ["very", "long label"]
  ],
  datasets: [{
    label: ['dataset'],
    backgroundColor: "rgba(38,120,255,0.2)",
    borderColor: "rgba(38,120,255, 1)",
    data: [90, 90, 90]
  }]
};

var options = {
  responsive: true,
  tooltips: false,
  plugins: {
    title: {
      text: 'Basic example',
      position: 'bottom'
    }
  },
  scales: {
    r: {
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      ticks: {   
        stepSize: 25
      }
    }
  }
};

new Chart('chart', {
  type: 'radar',
  plugins: [{
    afterLayout: chart => {
      chart.getDatasetMeta(0).rScale._pointLabelItems.forEach(o => o.textAlign = 'center');      
    }
  }],
  data: data,
  options: options
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <canvas id="chart" width="500" height="450"></canvas>
```